# Suma php y SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

Hola estoy trabajando php con sql server y necesito algo de ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo esta consulta

```
$sql = "select saldo_final from cuentas where doc = '1098788811'";

$consulta = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while($datos = sqlsrv_fetch_array($consulta, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
     print_r($datos);
}
```

El caso es que me trae los siguientes resultados

```
Array ( [0] => 12492.0000 ) Array ( [0] => 4006.0000 ) Array ( [0] => 4094.0000 )
```

Lo que necesito es coger esos 3 valores por php y sumarlos

Comment: ¿Y por qué no los traes ya sumados cuando haces la consulta SQL? Lo único que justificaría que los traigas individual es si también necesitaras cada dato para otra cosa.

Comment: pero igual lo puede traer de las 2 formas por ejemplo 'select a, b, a+b as "suma" from tabla'

Comment: Hola gracias por las respuestas, yo sabia que la suma se podía hacer por la consulta de sql sin necesidad de hacer algo por PHP pero quería ver como se hace propiamente por PHP ya que es lo que estoy estudiando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer en php:

```
$suma = 0;
while($datos = sqlsrv_fetch_array($consulta, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
     print_r($datos);
     $suma += $datos['saldo_final'];
}
```

Si lo quieres hacer en sql:

```
$sql = "select SUM(saldo_final) from cuentas where doc = '1098788811'";
```

Answer (score 0):

@alanfcm

Hola gracias por la respuesta
La consulta me quedo así, quite el

```
SQL_FETCH_NUMERIC
```

para poder llamar el campo "saldo_final" porque poniéndolo solo me trae un array de indices numéricos

```
$suma = 0;
while($datos = sqlsrv_fetch_array($consulta))
{
    print_r($datos);
    $suma += $datos['saldo_final'];
    echo $suma;
}
```

esto me trae lo siguiente

```
Array ( [0] => 12492.0000 [saldo_final] => 12492.0000 ) 12492Array ( [0] => 4006.0000 [saldo_final] => 4006.0000 ) 16498Array ( [0] => 4094.0000 [saldo_final] => 4094.0000 ) 20592
```

al final puedo ver la respuesta que es 20592, el problema es que si quito el

```
print_r($datos);
```

me trae lo siguiente

```
124921649820592
```

que técnicamente esta bien, lo que me muestra ahí es 12492 que es el primer dato obtenido, luego me muestra 16498 que es el resultado de ese primer dato sumado con el segundo, de ultimo me trae 20592 que es el resultado final, y solo quiero ese dato, el final