# Sumar arrays de una consulta MySQL en PHP -

Tags: php, array

Realize una consulta a mi base de datos la cual me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
[400,600]
```

> Nota: esta consulta es realizada con **mysqli** donde obviamente en array es llamado desde un bucle `while` de esta manera `$columna_gastos['costo_gastos']`

Entonces necesito que los valores de respuesta de ese array se puedan sumar entre si y que el resultado sea el siguiente:

```
1000
```

Este es el código del cálculo:

```
    while($columna_gastos = $resultado_del_query_gasto->fetch_assoc()){
     if(true){
        $total_gasto[$contador_get_values_gastos][0] = $datos_de_viaje_cond_clie[$contador_get_values_gastos][0];
        $total_gasto[$contador_get_values_gastos][1] = $total_gasto[$contador_get_values_gastos] + $columnas_de_gastos['PRECIO_GASTO'];

        $contador_get_values_gastos = $contador_get_values_gastos + 1;  
      }

  }
```

> El error yase en esta linea de código: `$total_gasto[$contador_get_values_gastos][1] = $total_gasto[$contador_get_values_gastos] + $columnas_de_gastos['PRECIO_GASTO'];`

Comment: Qué error te dispara al hacer la sumatoria?

Comment: Conteste una pregunta similar aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184280/suma-php-y-sql-server/184281#184281

Comment: Undefined offset: 0  - Me imagino que es por que en la linea del error **$total_gasto**cuando empieza a contar no vale nada. Entonces sumarlo por ende da un error de que la posición **0** del array no esta definido

Comment: ¿Solo necesitas ese dato? Si es así es mejor traerlo sumado desde la consulta mediante `SUM(columna)`

Comment: El problema es que estoy llamando una serie de datos del la base de datos los cuales tienen atributos distintos como por ejemplo *COD_VIAJE* y para cada viaje debe de dar un total. Es decir: Necesito sumar solo los que tengan el *COD_VIAJE* 001 y sumar ademas los que tienen el *COD_VIAJE* 002

Comment: No debería haber problema al sumar, probablemente uno de esos arreglos no tiene el índice que estás asignando, probá depurando esas variables y ver en dónde no existe dato.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de como vienen los datos para poder ayudarte mejor . Puedes hacer un `print_r($datos);` donde $datos es el conjunto de datos que te trae la consulta.

Comment: Si $total_gasto[$contador_get_values_gastos]  es un array, ya que a la izquierda del igual tomas el elemento 1, no puede ser el primer sumando, ya que estarías sumando un valor a un array.